# Unique URL to each tab

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs

I have 3 tabs in my 'my-account' page of my website.

when you go here for example:
https://mywebsitename.com/my-account/ you will have 3 tabs to choose from.

The problem is that when you go to tab 2 it's the same URL.

I would like it to be 
https://mywebsitename.com/my-account/#tab2

Here is my JS

```
(function($) {          
       $(document).ready(function(){

        $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

            $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
            $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        })

    })
    })(jQuery);
```

And here is what I have in my wordpress functions.php file

```
// The tabs in the my account page
function tabs() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'tabs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/tabs.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tabs' );
```

Any help will be amazing,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript when a tab is selected:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, "newUrl");
```

In your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        // BugFix - if page is loaded without #tab_id set in URL, the attribute location.hash is empty and then the new URL gets messy. So we have to check if location.hash is present and take proper action.
        if(location.hash.length > 0)
            window.history.pushState(null, null, location.href.replace(location.hash,"#"+tab_id));
        else
            window.history.pushState(null, null, location.href+"#"+tab_id);
        // End-of-BugFix
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

    // The following code will extract the hash part - after #, check if it is given, try to find a tab with that attribute and select it.
    var selection = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    if(selection.length > 0)
    {
        if($('ul.tabs li[data-tab="'+selection+'"]').size())
            $('ul.tabs li[data-tab="'+selection+'"]').click();
    }

});
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Is there some error on the console or just nothing happens? Have you tried to write just the upper part - function .click() ? It should change the URL of the window when you click on tabs. The part after comment should select the proper tab on window reload.

Comment: When I click on the tab, it does show me the #tab-2 in the url but when I open sitename.com/page/#tab-2 in a new window it does not open the tab, just the page

Comment: Looks like I've messed some languages :) Try replacing `strlen(selection) > 0` with `selection.length > 0`

Comment: It's working really good. but one more thing. when I click on the link it display it like that https://www.sitename.com/page/#tab-2https://www.sitename.com/page/ instead like that https://www.sitename.com/page/#tab-2

Comment: I found the error - it happens when you load the page with no #tab_id in its address. See corrections in the code above. :)